# Separate/pull capabilities from another JS file

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Ok so I'm trying to put the capabilities declaration for my Appium tests into another file and just reference it but I'm having no luck so far with using classes, functions, arrays and even global variables. I have also tried pulling it from a csv file but since JS is asynchronous that didn't work either.

I am not very familiar with JS and honestly stumped so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appeciated!

Here's the code that I'm trying to seperate/make a reference for:

```js
const opts = {
  port: 4723,
  desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    platformVersion: "8.1.0",
    deviceName: "Nexus 6P", 
    app: "C:/Users/reina.reinhart/KonyWorkspace/temp/dcpApp/build/luaandroid/dist/luavmandroid.apk",
    automationName: "UiAutomator2",
    noReset: true
  }
}
```

Comment: in js you have to explicitly declare exports as well as imports https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules

the code you have above won't export anything

Comment: @DanielLizik Thanks so much! That link had very clear explanations. I had actually tried exports before but I missed out the $ and ` haha